# IPv6 default route not being installed from RA

Tags: ipv6, juniper-junos, juniper-srx

> - Platform: Juniper SRX300
> - Version: JUNOS 15.1X49-D160.2
> - ISP: [Midco](https://www.midco.com/)

I currently have an issue where the IPv6 default route is not being installed from the CMTS RA.  Try as I might, I cannot get the SRX to pick up and install the default route.  I have a DHCPv6 assigned GUA on the link, I have DHCPv6-PD assigned /64 subnet going back and being installed on the inside interface etc, just no default route.

> Interface Map
>
> - **ge-0/0/0** - Internal
> - **ge-0/0/5** - ISP

---

Currently `show route`...

```
2001:48f8:4029:0:d7b:f865:2051:f208/128
               *[Direct/0] 00:07:59
                > via ge-0/0/5.0
                [Local/0] 00:07:59
                  Local via ge-0/0/5.0
2001:48f8:402a:19b1::/64
               *[Direct/0] 00:07:50
                > via ge-0/0/0.6
2001:48f8:402a:19b1::1/128
               *[Local/0] 00:08:01
                  Local via ge-0/0/0.6
fe80::ee13:db00:6d8:b300/128
               *[Local/0] 13:43:00
                  Local via ge-0/0/0.6
fe80::ee13:dbff:fed8:b305/128
               *[Local/0] 00:08:12
                  Local via ge-0/0/5.0
```

Notice the distinct lack of a default route.  `show ipv6 router-advertisement`...

```
Interface: ge-0/0/5.0
  Advertisements sent: 429, last sent 00:00:08 ago
  Solicits received: 430, last received 00:00:00 ago
  Advertisements received: 898
  Solicited router advertisement unicast: Disable
  Advertisement from fe80::242:5aff:fe1d:b019, heard 00:00:01 ago
    Managed: 1
    Other configuration: 1
    Link MTU: 1500 bytes
    Reachable time: 3600000 ms
    Default lifetime: 1800 sec
    Retransmit timer: 0 ms
    Current hop limit: 64
```

Currently `show interfaces terse` (abbreviated)...

```
Interface               Admin Link Proto    Local                 Remote
ge-0/0/0                up    up
ge-0/0/0.6              up    up   inet6    2001:48f8:402a:19b1::1/64
                                            fe80::ee13:db00:6d8:b300/64
ge-0/0/5                up    up
ge-0/0/5.0              up    up   inet6    2001:48f8:4029:0:d7b:f865:2051:f208
                                            fe80::ee13:dbff:fed8:b305/64
```

---

Configuration...

```
show configuration interfaces
ge-0/0/0 {
    flexible-vlan-tagging;
    native-vlan-id 1;
    unit 6 {
        vlan-id 6;
        family inet6;
    }
}
ge-0/0/5 {
    unit 0 {
        family inet6 {
            dad-disable;
            dhcpv6-client {
                client-type stateful;
                client-ia-type ia-pd;
                client-ia-type ia-na;
                update-router-advertisement {
                    interface ge-0/0/0.6 {
                        managed-configuration;
                        other-stateful-configuration;
                    }
                }
                client-identifier duid-type duid-ll;
                update-server;
                retransmission-attempt 6;
            }
        }
    }
}

show configuration protocols
router-advertisement {
    interface ge-0/0/5.0 {
        managed-configuration;
        other-stateful-configuration;
    }
}

show configuration security
forwarding-options {
    family {
        inet6 {
            mode flow-based;
        }
    }
}
policies {
    from-zone trust to-zone trust {
        policy trust-to-trust {
            match {
                source-address any;
                destination-address any;
                application any;
            }
            then {
                permit;
            }
        }
    }
    from-zone trust to-zone untrust {
        policy trust-to-untrust {
            match {
                source-address any;
                destination-address any;
                application any;
            }
            then {
                permit;
            }
        }
    }
    from-zone untrust to-zone trust {
        policy untrust-to-trust {
            match {
                source-address any;
                destination-address any;
                application junos-icmp6-all;
            }
            then {
                permit;
            }
        }
    }
}
zones {
    security-zone trust {
        host-inbound-traffic {
            system-services {
                all;
            }
            protocols {
                all;
            }
        }
        interfaces {
            ge-0/0/0.1 {
                host-inbound-traffic {
                    system-services {
                        all;
                    }
                    protocols {
                        all;
                    }
                }
            }
            ge-0/0/0.6 {
                host-inbound-traffic {
                    system-services {
                        all;
                    }
                    protocols {
                        all;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    security-zone untrust {
        interfaces {
            ge-0/0/5.0 {
                host-inbound-traffic {
                    system-services {
                        dhcpv6;
                        ping;
                        traceroute;
                    }
                    protocols {
                        router-discovery;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help/ideas would be truly appreciated.

---

Updated with additional output below...

```
show dhcpv6 client binding interface ge-0/0/5.0 detail 

Client Interface/Id: ge-0/0/5.0
     Hardware Address:             ec:13:db:d8:b3:05
     State:                        BOUND(DHCPV6_CLIENT_STATE_BOUND)
     ClientType:                   STATEFUL
     Lease Expires:                2019-04-19 14:04:10 UTC
     Lease Expires in:             2555595 seconds
     Lease Start:                  2019-03-20 14:04:10 UTC
     Bind Type:                    IA_NA IA_PD
     Preferred prefix length       0
     Sub prefix length             0
     Client DUID:                  LL0x3-ec:13:db:d8:b3:05
     Rapid Commit:                 Off
     Server Identifier:            ::
     Update Server                 Yes
     Client IP Address:            2001:48f8:4029:0:d7b:f865:2051:f208/128
     Client IP Prefix:             2001:48f8:402a:19b1::/64

DHCP options:
    Name: server-identifier, Value: LL_TIME0x1-0x5694c708-00:1a:64:99:79:e4
    Name: dns-recursive-server, Value: 2001:48f8:11::10,2001:48f8:11::11

Update RA interfaces:
     Interface: ge-0/0/0.6
            RA Prefix:      2001:48f8:402a:19b1::/64
```

Updated with additional outputs suggested by JTAC...

```
monitor traffic interface ge-0/0/5.0 matching "icmp6 or (udp port 546 or 547)" no-resolve extensive 
Address resolution is OFF.
Listening on ge-0/0/5.0, capture size 1514 bytes

01:03:01.746789  In 
        Juniper PCAP Flags [Ext, no-L2, In], PCAP Extension(s) total length 16
          Device Media Type Extension TLV #3, length 1, value: Ethernet (1)
          Logical Interface Encapsulation Extension TLV #6, length 1, value: Ethernet (14)
          Device Interface Index Extension TLV #1, length 2, value: 36096
          Logical Interface Index Extension TLV #4, length 4, value: 76
        -----original packet-----
        PFE proto 6 (ipv6): (class 0xe0, hlim 255, next-header: ICMPv6 (58), length: 32) fe80::242:5aff:fe1d:b019 > ff02::1: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, router advertisement, length 32
        hop limit 64, Flags [managed, other stateful], pref medium, router lifetime 1800s, reachable time 3600000ms, retrans time 0ms
          source link-address option (1), length 8 (1): 00:42:5a:1d:b0:19
            0x0000: 0042 5a1d b019 
          mtu option (5), length 8 (1):  1500
            0x0000: 0000 0000 05dc 

show ipv6 neighbors 
IPv6 Address                 Linklayer Address  State       Exp Rtr Secure Interface 
fe80::242:5aff:fe1d:b019     00:42:5a:1d:b0:19  stale       792 yes no      ge-0/0/5.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From JTAC...

> The issue you are facing is described on internal PR.
>
> Workaround
>
> - Configure IPv6 default route manually.
> - Add prefix info to the RA sent
>
> Known issue will be resolved in:
>
> - junos:15.1X49-D180
> - junos:17.4R3
> - junos:18.1R4
> - junos:18.2R3
> - junos:18.3R2
> - junos:18.4R2
> - junos:19.1R2
> - junos:19.2R1
>
> Tentative release for 15.1x49-D180 is end of May.

I've had to configure the default route manually as the workaround, as I do not control the ISP's CMTS.  This is accomplished by retrieving the neighbor LLA via snooping on the RA via `show ipv6 router-advertisements`, and using it as a qualified next-hop for default via the following command...

```
set routing-options rib inet6.0 static route ::/0 qualified-next-hop fe80::242:5aff:fe1d:b019 interface ge-0/0/5.0
```